# Is RandomForestRegressor predict() fundamentally slow?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I can only make 2-3 predictions per second with this model which is super slow.
When using `LinearRegression` model I can easily achieve 40x speedup.

I'm using `scikit-learn` python package with a very simple dataset containing 3 columns (`day`, `hour` and `result`) so basically 2 features.
`day` and `hour` are categorical variables.
Naturally there are 7 `day` and 24 `hour` categories.
Training sample is relatively small (cca 5000 samples).
It takes just a dew seconds to train it.
But when I go on predicting something it's very slow.

So my question is: is this fundamental characteristic of `RandomForrestRegressor` or I can actually do something about it?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,
                              max_features='auto',
                              oob_score=True,
                              n_jobs=-1,
                              random_state=42,
                              min_samples_leaf=2)
```

Comment: Can you give the data and complete code for us to duplicate the behaviour? Also post information about the versions of python, scikit-learn, numpy, and your system.

Comment: What times are you experiencing? Are you predicting examples individually in a loop or all at once?

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester hmm good question... currently I do it in a for loop due to broader program requirements but I could change it to make it predict all at once... let me test that and I'll get back to you with results.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester you were right on the spot... I guess I got away on linear regression with it but with random forest there is some significant setup time before each prediction. I ran 280 predictions. Avg. time was 29.2s ran the same predictions simultaneously (passing single DataFrame) -> avg. time was 117ms. Ans that is over 200x speedup.

Comment: The prediction code is cython if I recall correctly, so the the more data you can pass to `predict` at the same time, the less time you spend in pure python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some steps to optimize a RandomForest with sklearn

1. Do batch predictions by passing multiple datapoints to `predict()`. This reduces Python overhead.
2. Reduce the depth of trees. Using something like `min_samples_leaf` or `min_samples_split` to avoid having lots of small decision nodes. To use 5% percent of training set, use `0.05`.
3. Reduce the number of trees. With somewhat pruned trees, RF can often perform OK with as little as `n_estimators=10`.
4. Use an optimized RF inference implementation like [emtrees](https://github.com/jonnor/emtrees). Last thing to try, also dependent on prior steps to perform well.

The performance of the optimized model must be validated, using cross-validation or similar. Steps 2 and 3 are related, so one can do a grid-search to find the combination that best preserves model performance.

Comment: Point number 1 was the solution to my problem... thank you

Comment: Are there any downsides of running the predict in batches vs one by one?

Comment: @tiger_groove - no, not if you have multiple samples available. The results will be identical. If datapoints come in one-by-one at a high rate, then one can collect them into "microbatches" and predict on those. Slightly more complicated, but might be a win in terms of computational efficiency